# Include from/with function in php

Tags: php, function, include

I've been struggling with a php script including another, so I figured I could maybe use some help...

Basically what I want is to include a php file (call it content-1.php) into base.php with a function in functions.php.

The idea is that I want to include different files depending on $_GET-variables. I'm looking for something like this:

base.php

```
include("functions.php");
$api->getContent($_GET["content"]);
```

functions.php

```
class api {
function getContent($content) {
    if (isset($content)) {
        if (file_exists("/content/" . $content . ".php")) {
              return include("/content/" . $content . ".php");
        }
    }

    return include("/content/content-1.php");
}

function getName() {
   //Some function...
}

}
$api = new api;
```

content-1.php

```
echo "Hello world.";
echo $api->getName();
```

Everything seems to work (echoing Hello World.) until I try to reach $api from the content-1.php. I get a "Fatal error: Call to a member function of a non-object"..

But if I include content-1.php directly into base.php so it just looks like this:

base.php

```
include("functions.php");
include("/content/content-1.php");
```

Everything works calling $api and everything!

So, if I haven't been too messy, I wonder how I could include the content with the getContent() function and still be able to pass variables like if I included the file right away?

(Sorry for complicated description, I tried to simplify the code I really working with so if there is any errors in paths or syntax thats not the real problem but just some pasting-mistake..!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this happens is that the `$api` variable is only visible outside the function scope. You could add a line into the function like this:

```
function getContent($content) {

    $api = $this;

    // The rest of the code

}
```

**Side note!**

The code in the function has a serious security issue! It is possible to include ANY file as it is now. If the value of `$_GET['content']` is equal to `'../../../passwords.txt'` (just an example) the file `passwords.txt` would be included and the visitor would be able to view all your passwords.

To help this issue you should construct a list of available files, so that you choose which files CAN be included. To make this easier it can be done dynamically.

```
function getContent($content) {

    $api = $this;  // Make the $api avaiable to included file.

    $path  = 'path/to/contents/directory';
    $files = scandir($path);

    // Remove the two 'dot' directories
    $files = array_diff($files, ['.', '..']);

    // Now you check if the provided $content file name exists and in fact is a file.
    $filename = trim($content, '/.') . '.php';

    if(in_array($filename, $files) && is_file($filename)) {

         return include('/content/' . $filename);

    }

    return include('/content/content-1.php');
}
```

Now you can be sure an attacker would only be able to include files from the `contents` directory.

**UPDATE**

Question:

> How can I declare new variables in the included file and use them in the script executing the `getContent()` function?

There is a way to accomplish what you are asking for without any fragile code. You could pass by reference another variable declaring an array to the function. The function would look like the following:

```
function getContent($content, array &$variables = []) {...
```

The restriction with this approach is that you can only declare new variables like the following:

```
$variables['new_variable_name'] = 'new_variable_value';
```

Now when you call the call the function you have the option to pass another argument declaring an array to it. This array will hold the variables declared in the included file.

```
$variables = [];

$api->getContent($content, $variables);
```

Now you can access the variables like so:

```
$variables['new_variable'];
```

You can also `extract()` them into the current scope. This can lead to problems, so I have added the flag `EXTR_SKIP` to indicate PHP that it should ignore existing variables with the same name. You can set the flag `EXTR_PREFIX_ALL` and provide a third argument to `extract($variables, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'prefix')`. This will prefix all extracted variables and help you avoid naming collisions.

```
extract($variables, EXTR_SKIP);
```

There are restrictions when using a function to include files, but the approach I described first (no extract) can help you distinguish which variables are associated with what include.

I hope is useful.

Comment: Awesome answer! Thanks a lot for the input regarding security! Although I had a solution, but yours is better! But how do I pass a variable the other way? If I want to declare or set a variable to use later in base.php?

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to be sure you were aware of the security issue as that can lead to serious headaches later down the developer road.

Comment: I have updated by answer to provide a solution to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try $this instead of $api:

content-1.php

```
echo "Hello world.";
echo $this->getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside of the `content-1.php` `$api` is actually `$this`;

```
<?php // content-1.php
$this->getName();
```

Comment: Ah thanks! But what is the real difference from including in content-1.php? And how do I do if I want to define a variable in content-1.php to use later in base.php?

Comment: I don't understand your first question. As for your second question its going to be a little bit tricky but what you want to do is not render the parent templates until you render the children templates. its a bit involved and there are already solutions out there that do this. Like zend framework 2 for instance.